# Clone a project and then how to upload it to my own repo

Tags: github, git-clone

I have cloned a repository to download the code, now I want to work on it and save it in my own private repository on GitHub. I don't want to contribute to the original project or submit changes or anything, it's just a personal project. When I try to do this, however, my git isn't working because I think it's already associated with the repository that I did the clone command from. How do I properly do what I'm talking about?

Comment: Use the 'fork' option on that repo in Github, and it will create a new one in your account. You can then clone that new repo and it will point it to that origin. Instructions are available on github, but it's a pretty basic function.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of deleting the `.git` (which removes the history of past commits), you can simply change the `origin` and point it to a new GitHub repository that you have first created.

```bash
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/me/myNewEmptyRepository
git push --mirror
```

That way, you have a full copy of the original repository, without making a fork.
You can then change it as you need.

Comment: This will also work if you don't want to push it to the same hosting service. EG if you want to host it on gitlab or bitbucket.

Comment: @Derek True. You can adjust the remote URL to your target repository hosting service.